# Изучаю canvas, передвижение обьектов на холсте

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на цифры от 1 до 9 изменялась скорость обьекта на холсте, но скорость не изменяется.

Вот код:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var wigth = canvas.wigth
    var height = canvas.height
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "Red"
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Red"
    
    var circle = function(x,y,radius,kek){ 
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,Math.PI * 2,false);
        ctx.stroke();
        if(kek){ctx.fill()};
        }
    
    
    var Ball = function(){
        this.x = 400/2;
        this.y = 400/2;
        this.speed = 5;
        this.xSpeed = 5;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
    }
    
    Ball.prototype.move = function(){
      this.x += this.xSpeed;
      this.y += this.ySpeed;
    
      if(this.x < 0){this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
      } else if (this.x > 400){
        this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed};
    
      if(this.y < 0){this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed;
      } else if (this.y > 400){
        this.ySpeed = -this.ySpeed};
    }
    
    
    Ball.prototype.draw = function(){circle(this.x,this.y,3,true);};
    
    Ball.prototype.setDirection = function(direction){
      if(direction === "up"){
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = -this.speed;
      };
    
      if(direction === "down"){
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = this.speed;
      };
    
      if(direction === "left"){
        this.xSpeed = -this.speed;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
      };
    
      if(direction === "right"){
        this.xSpeed = this.speed;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
      };
    
      if(direction === "stop"){
        this.xSpeed = 0;
        this.ySpeed = 0;
      };
    };
    
    Ball.prototype.speed = function(mem){this.speed = mem;}
    
    
    var ball = new Ball();
    
    var keyActions = {
      32:"stop",
      37:"left",
      38:"up",
      39:"right",
      40:"down",
    };
    
    
    $("body").keydown(function(event){
      var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
      ball.setDirection(direction)
    })
    
    var speeds = {
      1:1,
      2:2,
      3:3,
      4:4,
      5:5,
      6:6,
      7:7,
      8:8,
      9:9
    }
    
    $("body").keydown(function(event){
     var mem = speeds[event.keyCode];
     ball.speed(mem);
    })
    
    setInterval(function(){
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
      ball.draw();
      ball.move();
      ctx.strokeRect(0,0,400,400);
    },30);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: А как должно работать?

Comment: При нажатии цифры от 1 до 9 должна изменяться скорость мяча соответсвенно

Comment: Рекомендую посмотреть в консоль. Там отображены ошибки.

Comment: Используйте новый синтаксис. var устарел, замените его на let. Как вариант, уже можно использовать class в коде. Большинство браузеров его уже поддерживают.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").keydown(function(event){
  var direction = keyActions[event.keyCode];
  ball.setDirection(direction)
})

...

$("body").keydown(function(event){
 var mem = speeds[event.keyCode];
 ball.speed(mem);
})
```

а так правильно на 1 событие вешать две функции?

Comment: Это не ответ, а коммент, зачем хулиганить структуру сайта? Ну и кстати, так работает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491718/jquery-more-than-one-handler-for-same-event. А правильно или нет - кто бы знал, зависит от ситуации:) И мне сдается, что тут не та ситуация...

Comment: @ mrEvgenX, а как в коммент записать несколько строчек кода, чтобы это все не было 1 строчкой?

Comment: Разработчики не предусмотрели, но в данной ситуации этого не требуется. Это не похоже на уточняющий вопрос, а больше на искреннее любопытство. В любом случае, разве неуместно выкрутиться в духе "А правильно к `$("body").keydown` привязывать 2 обработчика?"?:)